# No images in PDF generated by Pandoc XeLatex Engine

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc, macos-catalina

Ive tried using `<img>` tag as well as the pandoc markdown format to add images.

```
## Architecture

<img src="blah.jpeg" title="Default title" alt="alt text" style="display: block; margin: auto;" />
```

```
![a](blah.jpeg "text"){width=30%}
```

Both of these worked when i converted MD to HTML and DOCX. I do not have any error messages even when I convert to a PDF. is there something wrong with my Pandoc ?
and different image formats do not help either.

Here is an image of the PDF

[image: The PDF Generated simply has a Blank space]

Comment: what pandoc and XeLaTeX versions are you using? try the latest...

Comment: I've got this exact same issue. It is definitely the XeLaTeX engine that is the complication, as without that everything works fine. XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019), pandoc 2.8 (nightly from Oct 12).

Comment: works for me with XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) on macOS 10.14, pandoc nightly, command used: `echo '![](image.jpg){width=30%}' | pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -o foo.pdf` What OS are you people on? Perhaps macOS Catalina?

Comment: @mb21 , I’m using the same version as you but on macOS Catalina. Maybe that’s the issue.

Comment: yeah, fairly certain it's Catalina, probably xelatex doesn't have file access permissions on the image...

Comment: [someone mentioned](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5848) this happens only with graphicx version higher than 51733, can you confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue here. But uninstalling and reinstalling MacTeX solved the bug.